# Calling Microsoft Graph API from AAD Authenticated .NET Core API

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I currently have a web application that uses Azure AD to authenticate a user. This generates a JWT token which is then sent to my .NET Core Web API, which authenticates and authorizes successfully. The relevant parts of the JWT token that is sent across looks like this when put into jwt.ms (if you need more on this let me know and I can update this):

```
"aud": "api://<api-clientid>",
"appid": "<webapp-clientid>",
"hasgroups": "true",
"oid": "<userid">,
"tid": "<tenantid>"
```

I need to get to the groups that the user is a part of, and as the user is part of more than 6 groups, I need to make a call to the Graph API in order to return all groups for the user. This is documented in the description of the access tokens [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens), which states I should make a call to [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userID}/getMemberObjects](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserID%7D/getMemberObjects).

I have tried using Postman to create a token to authenticate with the Graph API through the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), but I get the below error (removed irrelevant parts):

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '<api-clientId>' named '<api-displayName>'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource...",
    "error_codes": [
        65001
    ],
    "suberror": "consent_required",
    ...
}
```

I've tried following the [web API that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview) guide which seems to do exactly what I want to, using the [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web). When I have tried this, I run into a similar issue with a MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException saying that I require more consent from the user. I tried changing the audience of the token to be for https://graph.microsoft.com/ but this then fails the authorisation to my web API, and I cannot have multiple endpoints in the audience of the JWT. I also tried using ITokenAcquisition as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore), but this did not work either, with a similar error to Postman.

Finally, I tried following [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph) which also appears to do what I require, where I made sure my web API and my web client were set up in the same way that they do. The only change I had to make was a small change to the manifest of the API to include the client application Id in the "knownClientApplications", but this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, where either my web application needs to know that my web API might need permission to the Graph API, or I'm missing more configuration on my Azure AD. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if more information is needed I'll provide as much as I can!

Comment: If you want to call the graph api, you need to grant `Directory.Read.All` **Application permissions** to the web app, go to App registrations -> API Permissions -> Add a permission -> Microsoft Graph -> Application permissions and then grant administrator consent for the permission .

Comment: I've applied this and still getting this issue. Sorry I should have mentioned that I have also been testing with graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync() as it requires minimal permissions and getting the same error. I know I will need this eventually but just trying to get any call to the Graph API to work for now

Comment: If you are testing with `graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync()`, then you should call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberObjects` api, you need `Directory.Read.All` **delegate permissions**. Please try it.

Comment: I've been able to get both the getMemberObjects and the basic /me working, but only when forcing admin permissions onto my API. I haven't done anything for my API to access my web client's token, so this feels slightly wrong. To me, I shouldn't be forcing admin permission to User.Read to get /me to work, as it should be a permission that it pulls through from the web client. I understand that I will need to give some kind of admin permission for what I require, but why does User.Read need admin too?

Comment: If you only call the /me endpoint, you don't need admin permission. Do you also use OBO flow to call the /me endpoint?

Comment: I think I need the OBO flow because the token I create from my web application authenticates me for my web API, and not the Graph API. When I take the admin consent away from User.Read on my web API's Permissions, I no longer get the User.Read scope on the token that I generate for the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that admin has didn't consent the application.

Login to Azure AD as Global Administrator and `Grant admin consent`  API permission via `App registrations -> API Permissions -> Add a permission -> My APIs -> A -> Application permissions` to fix this issue.To fix this issue.

Comment: Is this meant to be on my web app or my API? I can't actually seem to add Application Permissions as it's greyed out. I did read somewhere online that there was a reason for this but I'd have to look this up again.

My web client does have an "access_as_user" permission which is a delegated permission that I set up. This is the scope that is defined on my JWT between my web client and API which seems to work between them

Comment: Since you are using `getmemberobjects` endpoint it requires `Directory.Read.All` permission please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmemberobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Yes I am aware, just tried applying this and still getting issues. been trying to use graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync() as it requires minimal permissions and getting this issue

Comment: Hi @SteveNorwood, Can you share us the details of authentication url you are using. Please mask the clientid/secrets while sharing as they need to be secured.